# How to avoid needing variable variables?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-apps-script

I'm creating a form that is processed with a google apps script that will dump the results into a google spreadsheet.  The form grows as needed using Javascript and DOM to duplicate the section with id="duplicate_me".

```
<form method="post" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="P_name">
    <input type="text" name="P_addr">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="duplicate_me">
    <input type="text" name="C1_name">
    <input type="text" name="C1_addr">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="first_duplicate">
    <input type="text" name="C2_name">
    <input type="text" name="C2_addr">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I need the script to do an appendRow() for each set of C? fields and order is important. IE:

```
function doPost(e) {
...
  sheet.appendRow([ e.parameter.P_name, e.parameter.P_addr, e.parameter.C1_name, e.parameter.C1_addr ] );
  sheet.appendRow([ e.parameter.P_name, e.parameter.P_addr, e.parameter.C1_name, e.parameter.C1_addr ] );
...
}
```

The only solution I can come up with is to make the digit in the C? a variable but I realize that's a poor solution and difficult to implement.

How can I get these variables into a form that will allow me to execute this command in a loop instead of manually creating an arbitrary number of these entries?

Thanks for your thoughts.

--Dave

Comment: What are "variable variables"?

Comment: From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php): "A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable."

Comment: Am currently using eval() to address the issue and will post a solution of this type once the system lets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is exactly correct.

In a loop, write `e.parameter['C' + i + '_name']`

Comment: When I try to access e.parameter.C1_name as e.parameter[C1_name] Google returns an error: `ReferenceError: "c1_firstname" is not defined.`

Comment: @Dave: `[]` expects a string.  You need to use string concatenation, as I showed in my answer.